# How can I remove the lock icon from a folder in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, icons

I have shared a folder on Windows 7. Its icon has a padlock decorator. I want to remove the lock symbol; how can I do so?

Answer (score 3):

Use icacls to reset (i.e use default acl)

```
icacls foldername /reset
```

You may need to run this from an elevated command prompt.

Comment: You probably want to run `icacls foldername /t /reset` to recurse into subdirectories.

Comment: @LeonidShevtsov that worked for me! if you've got Windows Explorer open at the time, you'll need to force a refresh to get rid of the golden padlocks.

Answer (score 2):

1. Right click the folder with the Padlock icon and click Properties.
2. Click Security tab and click "Edit…" button.
3. In the popped up box, click "Add…" button and type the name "Authenticated Users", without quotes and then click OK.
4. Click OK and exit.
   I don't recommend this for System folders.

Comment: it worked. thanks. but, isn't there a cleaner way to do it? This seems very tricky.

Comment: Might be done from the command line, not sure.

Comment: For non-English Windows installations you have to use the localized name. The localized name can be determined by checking the permissions of a folder without a lock.